# JUNIT with excel input data

Tags: java, excel, junit4

**how to do junit parameterised test with excel input data.**

```
       Excel data:

       name         age    expectedOutput
        Ravi        32              1
        Christiaan  29              2
        Anuj        31              0
```

I want to get values in test class based on excel heading names.
In parametrized class the order of excel columns  must match with parameters in  constructor.ex:

```
public testConstructor(String name,int age,int out){
//some code
}
```

Suppose if I interchange  name and age columns in excel,then I have to change constructor in test class like `testConstructor(int age,String age,int out`).

If columns changed then I need to change constructor in parametrized test class. Otherwise I am getting name value to age variable and age value to name variable in test class. How to get cell values based on header names with changing constructor params in test class?

In Easy Test frame work :

```
@RunWith(DataDrivenTestRunner.class)
@DataLoader(filePaths={testData.xls} , loaderType=LoaderType.EXCEL)
public class TestClass{

    @Test
    public void simplTestMethod(@Param(name="name")String name , @Param(name="age")int    age , @Param(name="expectedOutput")int expectedOutput){
    ...............//your test conditions here
    }
}
```

How to get this concept in JUNIT to get values on header names with out disturbing constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better to get actual data from excel file before your test in `setUp()` method. So you can get both column names and data at a runtime. But in this case you will have to iterate through values manually.

p.s. Take a look at [ApachePOI](http://poi.apache.org/) framework to work with excel files.

Answer (score 0):

Have your keyRows start with the name of the test method in the first cell and the following fields will be used for parameter name mapping. 
All test-data containing rows will have to start with a empty cell in the first column.

Just see the source at [ExcelDataLoader.loadFromSpreadsheet()](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/easetech/easytest/loader/ExcelDataLoader.java#L141-L161) and [ExcelDataLoader.initializeRowData()](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest-core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/easetech/easytest/loader/ExcelDataLoader.java#L171-L204) or the [Documentation](https://github.com/EaseTech/easytest/wiki/EasyTest-:-Loading-Data-using-Excel).